# Comparing files in two folders using batch script

Tags: batch-file, file-comparison

I have to compare the file in two folders which have file names like

folderA: [a.f90, b.f90, ...]
folderB: [a_recoded.f90, b_recoded.f90, ...]

I wish to compare a.f90 in folderA with a_recoded.f90 in folderB.

what is used is:

```
@echo off
set folderA=D:\folderA
set folderB=D:\folderARenamed
set /a i=0
set /a j=0
cd %folderA%
FOR %%f in (*.f90) DO ( set /a i+=1 & for %%r in (%folderB%\*.f90) DO (set /a j+=1 & if %i% EQU %j% FC %%f %% r ) )
```

It doesn't help me, can anyone help me how to do this comparsion.

Comment: Why this is not working?  
set /a i=0
set /a i+=1

Comment: It strikes me that if the files are recoded, they aren't going to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "folderA=D:\NONMEM7.3beta7.0"
set "folderB=D:\NONMEM7.3beta7.0Renamed"
for %%a in ("%folderA%\*.f90") do if not exist "%folderB%\%%~na_recoded%%~xa" echo %%~na_recoded%%~xa not found in %folderB%.
for %%a in ("%folderB%\*.f90") do for /f "delims=_" %%b in ("%%~na") do if not exist "%folderA%\%%~b%%~xa" echo %%~b%%~xa not found in %folderA%.
```

Comment: +1 This looks good to tell if the files exist or not - I thought the OP wanted to do a binary compare.  It's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the help, now I use the following code to loop through the folders also:

```
@echo off
set vss=D:\FolderA
set renamed=D:\FolderARenamed

cd %renamed%
FOR /D %%d in (*) DO (
   cd %renamed%\%%d
   FOR %%f in (*.f90, *.f, *.c) DO (
      if exist %vss%\%%d\%%f fc %%f %vss%\%%d\%%f
      if not exist %vss%\%%d\%%f fc %%f %vss%\%%d\%%~nf_Recoded.f90
   )
)
```